# Add randomness to a simple RSA encryption example

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption

I've just started playing with cryptography & public key encryption. I've created a small python program which is a literal translation of the algorithm given in http://gnosis.cx/publish/programming/cryptology2.pdf (See RSA example section).
The code is given below.

Using GPG, if you encrypt the same text using the same key more than once, it gives different ciphertext each time. Is it possible to add that kind of randomness to the program below (without resorting to complex high-level math :P)? So that I'll get different ciphertext each time I encrypt, & still be able to decrypt it?

```
def enc(message, pubkey) :
    msg = [ord(char) for char in message]
    e,n = pubkey
    c = [m**e%n for m in msg]
    return c

def dec(cipher, prikey) :
    d,n = prikey
    msg = [c**d%n for c in cipher]
    msg = [chr(m) for m in msg]
    message = ''.join(msg)
    return message


p, q = 47, 71
n = p*q
e = 79
d = 1019

pubkey = (e, n)
prikey = (d, n)

msg = 'Hello World!'
print msg
cipher = enc(msg, pubkey)
for c in cipher : print c,
decipher = dec(cipher, prikey)
print '\n', decipher
```

It gives following output :

```
Hello World!
285 1113 1795 1795 2237 1379 1848 2237 2560 1795 1287 1260 
Hello World!
```

Comment: "without resorting to complex high-level math" - if you don't want to use advanced math, you should probably get out of cryptography now. It'll only get harder.

Comment: Type `help(pow)` and take a look at the optional `z` argument, by the way.

Comment: Ohh I understand.. I meant is there a way for this simple, contrived example?

Comment: Funny enough, both current answers are correct. For security you do need a public key encryption with padding and random. For encrypting larger data values, as you do now, you would need a random session key as well. If you want to put in both, you will however have to go for sub-byte values :) Maybe just go for the random key, possibly prepend it with a 1 bit as you would get values smaller than the modulus after exponentiation if you don't (m=1 for instance)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Using GPG, if you encrypt the same text using the same key more than once, it gives different ciphertext each time.

Most public-key cryptosystems do not actually encrypt your data with your public key. Instead, they do something like this:

- Generate a random "session key".
- Encrypt the session key with your public key (using an asymmetric cipher like RSA or ElGamal).
- Encrypt the plaintext with the session key (using a symmetric cipher like IDEA or CAST5).
- Attach the encrypted session key and some metadata about the process to the ciphertext.

The reason for this isn't so much to make the results random, as to make encryption and decryption much faster—e.g., IDEA is much, much faster than RSA, so using IDEA on your 100KB of data and RSA on your 32 bytes of session key will be a whole lot faster than using RSA on the whole 100KB.

> Is it possible to add that kind of randomness to the program below?

Well, it's obviously not possible to add the same kind of randomness without changing the program to do the same kind of algorithm. But that's probably what you want to do anyway.

For simplicity, you could just use your PK algorithm for both encrypting the session key and encrypting the plaintext with the session key. You would of course need to adapt things to generate a session key pair, use the private session key to encrypt the plaintext, and encrypt the public session key to attach to the message (or vice-versa). That could be useful for learning purposes, even if it's not useful for a real-life program.

However, even for learning purposes, it's probably still better to create a toy symmetric algorithm. So, let's create a super-trivial one, 8-bit XOR encryption:

```
def symmetric_enc(message, key):
    return [ord(char) ^ key for char in message]

def symmetric_dec(cipher, key):
    return ''.join(num ^ key for num in cipher)

def asymmetric_enc(message, pubkey) :
    msg = [ord(char) for char in message]
    e,n = pubkey
    c = [m**e%n for m in msg]
    return c

def asymmetric_dec(cipher, prikey) :
    d,n = prikey
    msg = [c**d%n for c in cipher]
    msg = [chr(m) for m in msg]
    message = ''.join(msg)
    return message

def enc(message, pubkey):
    session_key = random.randrange(1, 256)
    return (asymmetric_enc(session_key, pubkey), 
            symmetric_enc(message, session_key))

def dec(message, prikey):
    session_key, body = message
    session_key = asymmetric_dec(session_key, prikey)
    return symmetric_dec(body, session_key)
```

Comment: Thank you! Now its much clearer how public key cryptography works.

Comment: There are few bugs in the program above. I have the corrected program & I suggested an edit but it got rejected. What should I do now?

Comment: @Rahul I edited in [your](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2825141) correct fix that `dec` should use `asymmetric_dec`, but the other suggestions were a bit too radical for reviewers (including me): Whether you use `pow` or `**,%` doesn't matter (personally I prefer the latter due to it being closer to mathematical notation); creating a slightly different `symmetric_dec` defies the intention of _symmetric_ encryption; and pulling the `.join` part out of `asymmetric_dec` is both misleading and seems to severely modify the intended behaviour. Great question and answer btw!

Comment: Thank you @TobiasKienzler but the code if used as it is gives error in `asymmetric_enc` too.

Comment: @Rahul Ah yes, `asymmetric_enc` expects a string but already gets an integer. In order to still use the version you gave in the question, I guess you'll need `session_key = chr(random.randrange(1, 256))`. Of course `ord(chr(...` is a bit inefficient, so your modification of `asymmetric_enc/dec` now makes sense. It's too difficult to spot for a brief review though, sorry for having rejected it. But it might be nicer to modify the `symmetric_enc` into `return ''.join(chr([ord(char) ^ key for char in message]))` for consistency - that way both enc/decryptions return and expect strings

Comment: Sigh, [edit reviews should show comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/150142/146482), or [edits should be able to link to a specific comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194277/146482)

Comment: @Rahul: Unfortunately, I can't see the rejected edit history; I'm sure there were valid issues with my code (which was completely untested…) that I could help the two of you resolve. If describing the problems in comments is too hard, and the edit process isn't working out well here, maybe post a permanent edited version at http://pastebin.com? (The `asymmetric_dec` function is intended to be identical to your `dec` except for the rename, by the way. The point is to show how to convert a pure-asymmetric system to a hybrid one as simply as possible.)

Comment: @abarnert Here is the code [link](http://pastebin.com/XmEBM3cc). I just removed some bugs relating to the type of data which gets passed to the functions & completed the program. Thanks again for the program, btw!

Comment: @abarnert [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2825141) said suggestion. Unfortunately currently the only way to find rejected edits is browsing the editor's suggestion history. There already is a mod-tool to view a posts history including these rejected suggestions, [I feature-requested making it available to OPs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192238/146482), though [simply showing rejected edits in the edit history](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/192260/146482) might just as well do the trick...

Comment: @Rahul: Some of your changes, I disagree with. Using `pow` is a good change to your original code, but it's completely unrelated to the question you were asking, so it's a distraction to put it in the answer. As for the type stuff… yeah, that needs to be fixed. It would all be a lot easier (and probably more useful, too) if your ciphertext were a string rather than a list of numbers, but again, that's an irrelevant improvement, so… I'll edit in the fix your way.

Answer (score 2):

What you need it called 'padding'. You should Google for PKCS#1 padding/OAEP padding. In real world cryptography messages are not encrypted directly by RSA - some other (pseudorandom) bytes are added to make encryption stronger, also adding randomness to output.

Comment: While you _can_ use OAEP for randomness, it's not used by most cryptosystems, including GPG. The reason for the randomness in GPG is that it's a hybrid cryptosystem, as explained in my answer, not a pure PK system.

Comment: @abarnert As PGP itself specifies PKCS#1 v1.5 as encryption method to encrypt the symmetric key (and this by definition includes random values) you may retract that statement (and the downvote, if any).

Comment: @owlstead: GPG, which is what the OP asked about, defaults to a simple CAST5(session_key), so that isn't relevant. But the point is that whether or not you use a random padding algorithm, you're _always_ going to get random results, because the session key itself is random, a fact that's central to the whole point of the hybrid system.

Comment: Sorry, but you downvote something that makes the result random, while you are advocating your own solution, which also makes the output random. Then you say your solution is the reason why it is random, while PKCS#1 v1.5 makes anything encrypted with it appear random. As said, I'm not against either answer, but I really don't see a reason to downvote here.